# Wait on a text to be appear in SitePrism Capybara Framework

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, capybara, site-prism

I tried to wait on a text before perform any action by follows SitePrism URL https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism  in this section>> "Methods Supporting Capybara Options".

```
@page.wait_until_<Element>_visible :text => "Some Text!!!"
```

But i am getting below error:

```
undefined method `zero?' for {:text=>"Some Text!!!"}:Hash (NoMethodError)
```

Why i am getting this error? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: If you go to the given url section ("Methods Supporting Capybara Options") which i provided, you will see the sample code there. I corrected my question, sorry.

Comment: Ok - so looking at the site_prism code - https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism/blob/master/lib/site_prism/element_container.rb#L134  - the generated method takes a timeout, and the options --  so it seems like you need to pass the timeout value if you want to pass other options : `wait_until_<Element>_visible <timeout value in seconds>, text: "Some Text!!!" `  - seems like an error in the documentation, or some old defaulting behavior was removed or something

Comment: @Tom - It worked!!! Thanks Tom

Comment: You might want to file an issue on the site_prism project about the README being wrong - and I've added my comment as an answer so you can mark the question answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the site_prism code - https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism/blob/master/lib/site_prism/element_container.rb#L134 the generated method takes a timeout, and the options. It seems like you need to pass the timeout value if you want to pass other options

```
wait_until_<Element>_visible <timeout value in seconds>, text: "Some Text!!!"
```

Seems like an error in the documentation, or some old defaulting behavior was removed or something

Answer (score 0):

*Old question*

For those still hitting this SO answer, this has been remedied in v3 of the API and is no longer an issue. See: https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#wait_until-methods

`wait_for_` methods now no longer exist, and you should just implicitly wait by calling `element` i.e. `my_button`

If you want it to wait, you can modify the `Capybara.default_wait_time` or pass in a wait key i.e. `my_button(wait: 3)`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22280858)

Comment: That's not going to happen because that link will be perm as an upgrading guide.

But fair point I'll amend accordingly.